# Why is the border of my button not showing?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am creating a slider with Reactjs and Tailwind css. The slider has an image, an overlay, and content.

The depth or order in which the different items overlay are the following, in the very back the image, then the dark overlay and last the content. For some reason the white border of my button is not being displayed and i don´t know why. The z-index of the button is the greater.

```
function Slider() {
  return (
    <section className='w-full h-[572px] relative'>
        <img src="../../../public/slider1.jpeg" alt="slider" className='w-full h-full object-cover' />
        <section className="flex w-full h-full absolute top-0 left-0 z-20">
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center w-[30%] px-[84px] items-start">
                <h2 className="text-white text-[32px] font-bold mb-[30px]">Dona una bicicleta nueva o usuada</h2>
                <p className="text-[20px] text-[#F8F7FA]">Envías la foto de la bicicleta que donas al WhatsApp 1138970475 y nos contactamos.</p>
                <button className="border-white bg-transparent border-solid rounded-[6px] text-white border-2 w-[150px] h-[48px] z-50">Conocé más</button>

            </div>
            <div></div>
        </section>
        <div className="w-full h-full absolute top-0 left-0 bg-black opacity-50"></div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Slider
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you provided:

```
function Slider() {
  return (
    <section className='w-full h-[572px] relative'>
        <img src="../../../public/slider1.jpeg" alt="slider" className='w-full h-full object-cover' />
        <section className="flex w-full h-full absolute top-0 left-0 z-20">
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center w-[30%] px-[84px] items-start">
                <h2 className="text-white text-[32px] font-bold mb-[30px]">Dona una bicicleta nueva o usuada</h2>
                <p className="text-[20px] text-[#F8F7FA]">Envías la foto de la bicicleta que donas al WhatsApp 1138970475 y nos contactamos.</p>
                <button className="border-white bg-transparent border-solid rounded-[6px] text-white border-2 w-[150px] h-[48px] z-50">Conocé más</button>

            </div>
            <div></div>
        </section>
        <div className="w-full h-full absolute top-0 left-0 bg-black opacity-50"></div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Slider
```

It seems like you have used the `border-solid` class, which doesn't actually exist in Tailwind CSS. The correct class to use for setting the border style to solid is `border`. Update the button's class like this:

```
<button className="border-white bg-transparent border rounded-[6px] text-white border-2 w-[150px] h-[48px] z-50">Conocé más</button>
```

This should fix the issue and display the white border around your button.